# Errors after upgrading to Milestone 5 release of Apache Cayenne 4.0

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

I just upgraded to Apache Cayenne 4.0 M5 and I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/cache/CacheManager  at
>   org.apache.cayenne.jcache.JCacheModule.configure(JCacheModule.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultInjector.(DefaultInjector.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.cayenne.di.DIBootstrap.createInjector(DIBootstrap.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.cayenne.di.DIBootstrap.createInjector(DIBootstrap.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.cayenne.configuration.CayenneRuntime.(CayenneRuntime.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.ServerRuntime.(ServerRuntime.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.ServerRuntimeBuilder.build(ServerRuntimeBuilder.java:234)
>     at
>   com.company.databases.postgresql.financedb.runtime.FinanceDBRuntime.getFinanceAccountsDBPostgreSQLRuntime(FinanceDBRuntime.java:11)

The changes I did was changing from new ServerRuntime("configfile") (which was flagged deprecated) to ServerRuntime.builder("configfile").build(). And... I used the Modeler to regenerate all classes, which changed to "Property.create("...

I downgraded to M4, reverted all the changes and everything worked fine.

Is this a bug in M5 release? Or how do I workaround this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer - please remove `cayenne-jcache-4.0.M5.jar` from your app dependencies if you are not planning to use JCache.

Longer answer - Cayenne 4.0.M5 features module auto-loading. So whenever you are putting any `cayenne-*.jar` on classpath, it will try to install its extensions in ServerRuntime. Specifically `cayenne-jcache-4.0.M5.jar` tried to install JCache-based QueryCache, and since JCache library was not available, the exception was thrown.

For more details and other M5 changes see the M5 [UPGRADE.txt](https://github.com/apache/cayenne/blob/4.0.M5/docs/doc/src/main/resources/UPGRADE.txt).